# Saving components during uninstall depending on condition

Tags: wix, uninstallation

My task is to save registry keys on uninstalling our product depending on condition.
For example, if the user will enable a special checkbox *"Don't delete my settings"*, the registry keys must to stay on. I know that the component element in wix has the special attribute "Permanent", but my installer must to delete all installed components on uninstall by default. Any ideas? How to do this in wix? Or I have to use a custom action?
Thank's for your time.

Comment: I found another one solution to save settings in registry: i added a condition to _RemoveRegistryValues_ action.Smth like `REMOVE="ALL" AND CHECKBOXVAL=1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The correct approach is backwards.

These registry keys should always remain on the target machine. This can be done by marking their components as *Permanent* as you mentioned or by setting an [empty GUID](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa368007%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) for them.

After that, on one of your uninstall dialogs you can add a "Delete settings" checkbox. This checkbox can then condition an uninstall custom action which deletes the registry entries.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, what about the following approach:

- author 2 components, which differ in Permanent attribute only
- add mutual exclusive conditions to these components, which depend on whether "Don't delete my settings" checkbox is set or not

Comment: I am also thinking about this solution. Only it's not really what i need. The checkbox must be set on during uninstallation. Hmm.. it is not possible